# How to get column values in 2 tables in a select query?

Tags: php, mysql

So I have 2 tables named tbl_admin and tbl_users. Each of them has a column named acct_type. All acct_type values in tbl_admin is 1 and in tbl_users, 0. I know it would be easy for me if I have just created one table for them. My question is, how can I query this so that I can redirect the admin to its page and the users to its page.

Here is my code

```
$uname = $_POST['txt_un'];
$pword = sha1($_POST['txt_pw']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_admin WHERE uname=? AND pword=?";


$stmt = $dbc->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $uname);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $pword);
$stmt->execute();

$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if ($row > 0) {
    if ($row['acct_type'] == 1) {
        header("Location: adminpage.php");
    } elseif ($row['acct_type'] == 0) {
        header("Location: userspage.php");
    }
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('Incorrect username/password');location.href='../index.php'</script>";
}
```

I know it will not work since I am only querying select from tbl_admin. Your help would be very much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Use a join, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest joining. I *would* suggest fixing your tables.

Comment: @HalfCrazed Yes I prefer fixing my tables. But if this will be the case, is there a solution?

Comment: @chris85 I'm new to joining. If you can guide me? But I'll try it, thanks.

Comment: What is the column the two tables share, userid?

Comment: First, you need to figure out what type of join to use. See: http://i.stack.imgur.com/66zgg.png

Comment: @chris85 both tables have the column acct_type which is set to 0 if user and 1 if admin

Comment: Oh, I thought the table structure was different. You can't join with this structure.

Comment: @chris85 then I guess the only solution will be to have 1 table or use different login pages for admin and user right?

Comment: Yes, 1 table is best. I'd make a tinyint column called "isadmin" with a default value 0. Then run an "insert into tbl_users (COLUMNS, isadmin) select COLUMNS, 1 from tbl_admin". The static 1 in the select is so all the admins are marked correctly. Duplicates may cause an issue as has been stated already.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that your table (tbl_admin,tbl_users) have the same number of columns
and each user entry in these two tables are unique. "you will have some serious problems in the future if not."

```
$uname = $_POST['txt_un'];
$pword = sha1($_POST['txt_pw']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_admin WHERE uname=? AND pword=? UNION SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE uname=? AND pword=?";


$stmt = $dbc->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $uname);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $pword);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $uname);
$stmt->bindParam(4, $pword);
$stmt->execute();

$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if ($row > 0) {
if ($row['acct_type'] == 1) {
    header("Location: adminpage.php");
} elseif ($row['acct_type'] == 0) {
    header("Location: userspage.php");
}
} else {
echo "<script>alert('Incorrect username/password');location.href='../index.php'</script>";
}
```

For additional info regarding UNION, please check: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Edit: as  Half Crazed suggested, this approach should only be done if each user is unique in both tables. If you have additional time, you should revise the way you fetch your users

Comment: What if a user exists in both tables? This is something that should be considered.

Comment: Then you have a problem; this is one of the reasons why you should use two tables. What if the values are different in each table, like the password? Which one should be used in that case?

Comment: Well I can't use union because I don't have the same number of columns. These are my columns:

tbl_admin: [link](http://i.imgur.com/N2KFPXp.png)
tbl_users: [link](http://i.imgur.com/eAYZT9g.png)

Thank you for understanding me..

Comment: you can do something like.

$query = "SELECT admin_id id,uname,pword,fname,mname,lname,acct_type FROM tbl_admin WHERE uname=? AND pword=? UNION SELECT stud_id id,uname,pword,fname,mname,lname,acct_type FROM tbl_users WHERE uname=? AND pword=?";  to achieve same column count but we still suggest you revise the way you do it, for long term effect

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for helping me in this query. Your answers are very much appreciated. I've figured out that I'll just make different log in forms for the admin and user for some purposes.